# Is excessive cURL intensive on the server?

Tags: php, curl

I am setting up a site where my users can create lists of names that gets stored in the database. They can then "check" these lists, and each name in the list is run through a cURL function, checking an external site to see if that name is available or taken (for domain names, Twitter names, Facebook names, gaming names, etc). There will be a drop down for them to select which type of name they want to find, and it checks that site.

Here's a code sample for a Runescape name checker:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://services.runescape.com/m=adventurers-log/display_player_profile.ws?searchName=" . $name);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);


    if (stristr($output,"non-member account")) {
        echo 'Not available';
    }
    elseif (stristr($output,"private profile")) {
        echo 'Not available';
    } 
    elseif (stristr($output,"top skills")) {
        echo 'Not available';
    } 
    else {
    echo 'Available';
}

    curl_close($ch);
```

Will this cause too much stress on the server? I'm thinking also of capping lists, so maybe only 1,000 names per list for free members or something, and they can upgrade to run bigger lists (maybe even smaller than 1,000 for free users). Another thing I could do is store the results locally (which I'll do anyway), and load it from there if the name was searched recently. But then it's not completely accurate.

Comment: Yeah, running that `cURL` sample 1000 times (for each name) is going to take forever - moreover, it's likely to get your IP address blocked by the sites you're querying.

Comment: curl itself is pretty lightweight. it's just doing an http request. But you're going to be hammering that url with a fresh http request for every request your users are doing.

Comment: @Ben D - Kind of related question: If the cURL was used enough, would it essentially DOS the site it's getting the results from if the server couldn't handle it?

Comment: It depends on your setup, assuming that you're running a loop rather than starting 1000 different threads, PHP will wait for a return value before starting the next request, so it shouldn't cause any service problems on the target machine (only a single connection will be open at once)

Answer (score 1):

The answer can only be "it depends."  It depends on how many users you have, how often those users hit the page in question, how beefy your hardware is, how much bandwidth your host allows, how much data is being transferred, and a million other things.

In general, you should locally (as in, on your server) cache as much data as you can from API responses.  That prevents unnecessary duplicate API requests for data that you already had at some point previously.  As for what data makes sense to cache, that is completely application/API specific, and something you will have to decide.  In general, good candidates for caching are things that don't change very often and are either easy to determine when they *are* changed, or not important enough that somewhat stale data will be a big deal.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is one of the rare situations where it doesn't depend. If you're running 1000 requests against a single URL you have two options: running them synchronously (one at a time), in which case - even under ideal conditions and assuming you don't get blocked - it's going to take a long time. If you instead run it asynchronously (and you're going to need a beefy machine to run 1000 simultaneous `cURL` calls) you're going to cause a DOS failure on most target machines (that's more concurrent connections than most machines can handle, particularly if they're running apache).

Comment: @BenD: If you're running only 1 request, then there's no problem, is there?  So then "it depends" on how many requests are being issued, among other things I noted.  You're also making the faulty assumptions that you must either do this synchronously, or async and all 1000 simultaneously, which is obviously far from the truth.  You can do them async, with a simultaneous cap that's appropriate for your hardware, for example.  This may be 500, 100, 50, or whatever other number, and "it depends" on the hardware involved.

Comment: The OP specifically asked about a scenario where a list of 1000 names was considered a small query, and at a minimum those names would be queried against several endpoints, so we're talking *several thousand cURL calls per submission at a minimum*. And I did suggest batching (hybrid synch and asynch) in my answer, but at the volumes the OP is talking about it's still going to be slow. Even with a distributed setup (where the OPs hardware is capable of rapidly running the large volume of calls), the resulting load on target servers will probably result in DOS or blocking for many domains.

Comment: @BenD: The OP said nothing in the question about typical list size, and suggested 1000 as the *maximum*.  Also, bear in mind the actual use-case for this tool: it takes your list of desired names and checks them against a service to see if they are taken.  I don't know about you, but I've never had a list of anywhere near 1000 desired names prior to registering for any service.  I would say 5-10 is a more likely average.

Comment: The OP said that 1000 would be the cap for *free users*, with larger lists available for paid users... this pricing structure suggests that the OP's expects to handle very large lists (I admit that I also wonder about what real-life scenarios would demand it, but the OP seems to think it a likely use-case). The OPs question is specially about how to handle very large volumes of cURL requests (he already knows how to run small numbers of them), so it makes sense to address this core concern: how to structure a system for handling thousands of calls.

Answer (score 0):

CURL requests are fundamentally slow, and PHP is, for the most part, a synchronous language, so unless you want to wait for each request to return (which, when I tested your command took ~1.2 seconds per request) your best bet it to either have PHP fork the curl requests using your OS's curl command via `exec` or to use non-blocking sockets. This article has a good explanation of how to do it:

https://segment.io/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/

However, you're still going to run into issues where the receiving host may not be able to handle the volume of requests you're sending (or it will blacklist you). You might have an easier time breaking the requests into batches (say ten names at a time) and then run those requests simultaneously against each host (Runescape, FB, etc)... this will let you run a few hundred simultaneous requests without hitting any one host too hard... It's still going to be a slowish process, and you might get your IP banned, but it's a reasonable approach.

Also, you might think about having the whole process broken down over a long-ish period of time... so a user uploads the list, and your server says "thanks, you'll receive an email when we're done"... then use a cron job to schedule the subsequent `cURL` requests over the course of an hour or so... which should help with all the above issues.